# Drain trap is too low for new vanity

Tags: plumbing

My wall drain pipe clears the vanity, but there is not enough depth for trap. That's why I am thinking running a 90 degree bend out of the wall upward. My concern is losing the trap seal.

Since wall drain pipe clears the vanity, I am thinking running 90 degree going up and then attaching the rest to the p-trap.

[image]

Not sure if this matters. Within the wall, drain pipe doesn't go straight down. It turns left and goes towards toilet.

Answer (score 6):

No you can't do that.

The P-trap depends on the weir which requires critical trap arm length and a slope that does not siphon the trap dry.  Your drawing siphons the trap.  You could add an aav but opening the wall might be easier.

https://www.jlconline.com/how-to/plumbing/maximum-length-for-fixture-drains_o

The other thing I've done is to make the p-trap assembly in a straight line to the back of the cabinet and then make a cut out in the shelf to accommodate the trap.  I've done this with both drawers and with shelves.

Comment: The shelf cutout suggestion is solid. I'd use a hole saw at each end of the slot to keep it fitting closely. If you happen to have a router, a bullnose bit run around the cutout will clean it up nicely. Give the raw edge a coat of paint or varnish to seal it up a bit.

Comment: Is the idea inherently unworkable, or was the problem with the proportions given in the drawing? I'm not familiar with plumbing but are there some code stipulations with the right-angle bends in a drainage line?

Comment: I'm a bit amazed - when I go to look for a vanity shelf they all have a ceiling board WITH a U-cut out to allow / support the trap to "dive" into. You can cover the hole and plumbing  with https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71Dao225ZCL._AC_SX355_.jpg or similar products

Comment: Why would opening the wall be easier than adding an AAV at the end of the trap arm, if there's space?

Comment: Would a loop of pipe which connects the two ends of the horizontal section and rises above the sink's overflow height be another way of meeting code, if one can figure out how to avoid it being too unsightly?  I think that's how island sinks are accommodated.  Alternatively, could the trap be moved next to the wall, and the sink pipe made to slope down toward it?

Answer (score 2):

No need for that, there tail pipe extensions that add length to get to a lower P trap like you have.[image: , text]
Picture courtesy Home Depot

Comment: He can't lower the trap because of the vanity shelf, like in his picture.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it sacrifice the shelf or at least a hole for the p-trap...

Comment: I'm sure Jimmy knows this. His point is that this answer doesn't address the specific question posed, which is how to create a suitable trap in the space available.

Comment: Yup I missed the shelf somehow, Duh.

Answer (score 1):

Use a t wye and a studor vent .right now you created an S trap.so the first 90 elbow from the sink needs to be a t w wye with a studor vent on top a min of 4 inches over trap weir

Answer (score 1):

If it comes to it, sacrifice the vanity shelf and get your waste pipes as close to perfect as you can. Future you will thank you, you can always add more storage/shelving elsewhere. You have one decent opportunity to get your sink drainage as good as you possibly can, function over form.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 90's use 45 degree fittings. 
This fixture cannot be further than 7ft from its vent.
And That particular offset can not be greater than 2ft.
 Same goes for pop up assembly to p-trap weir.
 The maximum is 2 ft.
Or you might create a dry trap not stopping sewer gas.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.